# Easiest way to switch NeoVim Control key shortcuts to command key

Tags: macos, vim, iterm2, neovim

tl;dr

Searching for a way to replace all shortcuts in neovim that use the control key with the command key on Mac

--

I just got started in using neovim as my main code editor

However I find hitting the control key way harder than the command key and a lot of the keyboard shortcuts for neovim use the control key

I would like the easiest way to replace all control key shortcuts with command key (they can also work both)

I have thought about using karabiner elements and creating an app specific remap of command key to control key (only when Im in iTerm2), however I dont think this is the best approach as then, I will for example not be able to paste with command V anymore.

There must be a way to replace the keyboard shortcuts in neovim that use control key with the command key?